# Find custom string index of an array by value - for multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have a bit of a problem with arrays.

I have a string as value, which is unique to an array index, e.g. "daa12d956752gja2":

```
g_nodeMapping["87686479/welcome.html"] = "daa12d956752gja2";
```

This string is what I know. What I need to get is the index, so "87686479/welcome.html". The thing is... I have dozens of arrays like this. It basically looks like this:

```
g_nodeMapping = [];
g_nodeMapping["8374628/test.html"] = "489fa3682975da";
g_nodeMapping["8953628/anothersite.html"] = "gi764295hf46";
g_nodeMapping["267857543/helpplx.html"] = "8653468te87a";
```

...

I tried the `indexOf` method, but it doesn‘t seem to find the array index for the value after the equation sign.

I can‘t change the array unfortunately.

Help is much appreciated. Sorry for the formatting, I'm on mobile.

Comment: `“` and `„` will cause a `SyntaxError` in Javascript. You might consider using `'` instead.

Comment: do you have really an array instead of an object?

Comment: I think so... If I type in g_nodeMapping into the browser console it says „object array“

Comment: try instead  array object : g_nodeMapping = []; g_nodeMapping = {};

Comment: As stated above, I can‘t change the array unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function `findCustomKey` that takes an array element (or value) as a parameter and returns the key. The following example shows that:

```
var arr = [];
arr["8374628/test.html"] = "489fa3682975da";
arr["8953628/anothersite.html"] = "gi764295hf46";
arr["267857543/helpplx.html"] = "8653468te87a";

function findCustomKey(ele) {
    let keys = Object.keys(arr);
    for (let keyEle of keys) {
        if (arr[keyEle] == ele) {
            return keyEle;
        }
    }
}

console.log(findCustomKey("489fa3682975da"));
console.log(findCustomKey("8653468te87a"));
console.log(findCustomKey("abcd123"));
```

The Output:

```
8374628/test.html
267857543/helpplx.html
undefined
```

*Another Version (EDIT added):*

Here is another way to code `findCustomKey`(the way to use it remains same):

```
function findCustomKeyV2(ele) {
    return Object.keys(arr).filter(k => arr[k] == ele)[0];
}
```

---

*Another Version:*

This version of the solution was added as the above code did not work on IE browsers. The following code worked on Firefox, Chrome and IE11 browsers.

```
var arr = [];
arr['8374628/test.html'] = '489fa3682975da';
arr['8953628/anothersite.html'] = 'gi764295hf46';
arr['267857543/helpplx.html'] = '8653468te87a';

var arrMap = new Map();
for (let k in arr) {
    arrMap.set(arr[k], k);
}

console.log(arrMap.get('489fa3682975da'));
console.log(arrMap.get('8653468te87a'));
console.log(arrMap.get('abcd123'));
```

Comment: It works on mozilla and chrome, but I get a SCRIPT5009 error in IE11 with edge compatibility. Any ideas why?

Comment: I had tried on Firfox and Chrome with no issues. I tried on the IE 11- I get the error `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error`. I searched the net (Google). There seems to no specific consistent reason, except the feature may not have been supported on the IE browser. There are various solutions in different contexts - I couldn't figure what the real issue is. If I find a proper reason I will post here.

Comment: @schokogabel332 I added alternative solution that worked on IE11 also. Please try and let me know - if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the key by getting all keys from the object/array and find the value.

```js
function getKey(object, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(k => object[k] === value);
}
   
var g_nodeMapping = [];
g_nodeMapping["8374628/test.html"] = "489fa3682975da";
g_nodeMapping["8953628/anothersite.html"] = "gi764295hf46";
g_nodeMapping["267857543/helpplx.html"] = "8653468te87a";
g_nodeMapping["87686479/welcome.html"] = "daa12d956752gja2";

console.log(getKey(g_nodeMapping, "daa12d956752gja2"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the other answer and it works. Thank you vers much for your solution.